# append a value in a list passed by argument in include_tasks - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to append some value in a list passed by argument to a task in the module `include_tasks`, my playbook struct looks like this.

```
some-folder/
|
|--- main.yml
|--- subtask.yml
```

In my `main.yml` file I've a list with some number and a `include_tasks` module, like this.

```
# my_list content is [1, 2, 3, 4]    
- include_tasks: subtask.yml list={{my_list}}

# I'll do something with this list later on other task
```

I want to append some content in `my_list` inside the `subtask.yml` and use this new list for something later, in my `subtask.yml` file I've tried the module `set_fact` like the example below, but it is not working like i expect..

```
- set_fact:
    list: "{{ list }} + [ 5 ]"
```

I want the list to be like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` when it exits the `subtask.yml` but it exits the same way it entered in the subtask file, the list content is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

What am I doing wrong?? Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

Using the struct of the files like

```
some-folder/
|
|--- tasks/
|      |
|      |--- main.yml
|      |--- subtask.yml
|
|--- vars/
|      |--- main.yml
```

In my file `some-folder/vars/main.yml` I've added this content.

```
my_list: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I've used this variable in the `some-folder/tasks/main.yml` and `some-folder/tasks/subtask.yml`, in my `tasks/main.yml` I changed the code to this.

```
- include_tasks: subtask.yml
```

And in the `tasks/subtask.yml` I've changed the code to this.

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list }} + [ 5 ]"
```

This solution worked